# Time Zone changed incorrectly on random boots

Tags: 20.04, timezone

A few days ago my system **time zone** started to be changed **incorrectly on random boots, from:

```
BST (London, United Kingdom)
```

to

```
GMT (Accra, Ghana)
```

I can correct this with:

```
$ timedatectl set-timezone Europe/London
```

But why is it happening and how can I correct it?

Comment: The "automatic time zone" feature relies on WiFi devices that are in the area. The MAC they broadcast is compared to a list of devices known to a Location Services API and the time zone is returned based on the GPS coordinates provided. Do you have a new neighbour who has recently moved from Africa? 

Comment: That can't be true because Wi-Fi is not enabled on my machine, just Ethernet.

Comment: Hmm ... not sure why your timezone is being changed, then. That relies on the Location Services API, which uses WiFi base stations for triangulation. A person's IP address is not used because VPNs can pop out anywhere in the world ... 